# Using `gq` to correctly wrap function arguments

Tags: formatting, wrapping

Consider editing the code

```
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two, var_three, var_four)
```

where the `textwidth` 'column' occurs just after `var_two`.

I would like to be able to press `gqq` on the line and it get formatted to:

```
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two, 
                         var_three, var_four)
```

Currently it does this:

```
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two, 
    var_three, var_four)
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are editing a file recognized by Vim as source code and therefore Vim's more sophisticated indenting is enabled<sup>1</sup> (check with `:set cindent?`) you can just do this:

```
:set cinoptions=(0
```

With `:set textwidth=50` I get this formatting of your example line:

```
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
                         var_three, var_four)
```

`cinoptions` allows you to tune how Vim indents various code constructs.

The `(N` option is described, in part, in `:h cino-(` thusly...

```
(N    ... When N is 0 or the unclosed parentheses
      is the first non-white character in its line, line up with the
      next non-white character after the unclosed parentheses.
```

But for this particular case the help for `WN` (`:h cino-W`) actually has a (counter) example that is more in line with your case:

```
WN    When in unclosed parentheses and N is non-zero and either
      using "(0" or "u0" ...

    cino=(0                         cino=(0,W4
      a_long_line(                    a_long_line(
                  argument,               argument,
                  argument);              argument);
      a_short_line(argument,          a_short_line(argument,
                   argument);                      argument);
```

We want it to look like the example on the left so `cinoptions=(0`.

Take a look at `:h cinoptions-values` for heaps of other ways to tune the indentation.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This doesn't apply to all languages. See the comments/chat for discussion about Python files having `nocindent` by default.</sub>

Comment: This doesn't work for me but I may be missing something. I have `:set cindent?` returning `cindent` and `:set cinoptions?` returning `cinoptions=(0`. Is there something else I am missing to get it to work?

Comment: What do you see when you use `gqq` after setting this?

Comment: Ok well the reason this initially didn't work was because I was using a `.py` file. When I changed the format it did work (y). I have no idea why it didn't work for `.py` however.

Comment: I don't use Python so not quite sure why but Vim doesn't set cindent automatically when I open a `.py` file...Okay, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570737/auto-indent-doesnt-work-when-using-vim-coding-python See if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found a Python fix if I run `setlocal cino=(0`. I would be really interested in what is going on that means I have to use this. This thread is relevant but I don't completely understand it http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/cino-0-not-working-as-expected-td1179529.html.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it working. I'll read up on the problem as I'm kind of curious myself.

Comment: Ok, it seems the issue is on my system is caused by Python files having `indentexpr` automatically set which overrides `cindent`. The above `setlocal` actually didn't work, I just did it not realising I was in a `.c` not a `.py` file! For anyone else stumbling across this, I can confirm running `set indentexpr=` does cause the `cindent` to work in Python.

Comment: Oh, you know, since indentation/formatting matters in Python maybe they figured having a lot of customizability isn't a good default configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75777/discussion-between-rwolst-and-b-layer).